# Why is my series wrong?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, power-series

Why is this series wrong and how does it differ from this other one?

We had to find the general term for the series: $ 1/3+2/9+1/27+2/81+1/243+2/729+\ldots $ where the index begins at $n=1$ So I came up with this (see image, first formmula) now the profsaid this isn't right and gave us the sln.(see image, second one), so the next time I have to explain why this is wrong. .

\begin{align}
\mathrm{an_{me}} &= \frac{3^{1+(-1)^n} - \frac{7}{2}[1+(-1)^n]}{3^n} \\
\\
\mathrm{an_{prof}} &= \frac{3-(-1)^{n+1}}{2\cdot 3^n}
\end{align}

Again where do these series differ? I can't see any difference besides that my formula is kinda messy!

Thnx.

Comment: When inserting $n=1$, your sequence gives $(3^0-7/2(-1)^1+1)/3^1 = (2 + 7/2)/3 = 11/6$, which clearly is different from $1/3$, while the professor's series correctly gives $(3-(-1)^2)/(2\cdot 3^1) = 2/6 = 1/3$.

Comment: Hmm. If the general term is $$1/3+2/9+1/27+2/81+1/243+2/729$$ then the series seems to be $\\$  $$  (1/3+2/9+1/27+2/81+1/243+2/729) + (1/3+2/9+1/27+2/81+1/243+2/729)+(1/3+2/9+1/27+2/81+1/243+2/729) + ...   $$ $ \\ $ which I would assume to be -for some possible solution of this divergent case-  $(1/3+2/9+1/27+2/81+1/243+2/729)\zeta(0)$. What do you think?

Comment: Thank you for your effort celtschk and DonAntonio and I apologize becuase I made a mistake writing it into mathcad since i didn't know how properly write equations here. If you could take a look at it again please?

Comment: I can't follow you on this one Gottfried Helms! What exactly do you mean?

Comment: With the revised formula, I now get the same result for both.

Comment: Well yeah, that's why I came here. I tried to find any difference for two hours now but failed. Maybe he's trying to say that formulas should be short and simple or...I don't know.

Comment: Why don't you ask your prof why he considers your formula wrong?

Comment: That's what I have to find out. Probably he will tell us the next lecture but he gave it to us as an assignment first.

Comment: @hackyou: if the "general term" is independent of some index, then it means it is constant, and thus be equal for any term of the series... -and what happens if you add infinitely many equal terms? (And I can't see any reference to a variable index in your "general term")

Comment: I see the general term more something like a function of the index and not independent or constant. If you add infinitely many equal terms then probably you'll get infinity.

Comment: @GottfriedHelms: you seem to be assuming the thing following the expression "We had to find the general term for the series:" is the proposed general term. As I read the question, it is in fact the series, whose general term is presented later on.

Comment: No, that's the series, the terms of the series starting from the first one which is 1/3...and so on.

Comment: Well I see an expression with 6 terms in a sum - which is finite and thus not a series. So what can it mean "the general term"? I can understand when the "general term" is a function of an index, say $i$ going from $0$ (or $1$) to $\infty$. That function may be somehow complicated, like the given sum, for instance- no problem. But if there is only a constant expression - what could I read from it? - It must be that the professor made a series of constant terms. And a series, whose general term is $a$ like $ a + a + a + a + ...$ might be interpreted as $a(1+1+1+1+...)=a \zeta(0)$ - if at all...

Comment: This IS a series, like I said it's my first post here and I can't format equations properly, that's why there's a plus and three dots missing after the term 2/729. Thank You.

Comment: Ahh, so someone could have helped you (and me) to improve the notation for indicating the series "1/3 + 2/9 + 1/81 + 2/243 + ..." where the terms are "1/3^k" for k=1,3,5,7,... and "2/3^k" for k=2,4,6,8,... . Ok, I get this now. Please pardon me for any inconvenience!

Comment: Kein problem herr Helms. Danke fur den versuch zu helfen. :)

Comment: :-) Hatte gerade noch Zeit vor dem Schlafengehen. Have a good night...

Comment: How did you derive your answer, by the way? It seems harder to arrive at than the professor's solution. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's multiply up to make the denominators match:

\[\frac{3^{1+(-1)^n} - \frac{7}{2}[1+(-1)^n]}{3^n}
 = \frac{2\cdot 3^{1+(-1)^n} - 7[1+(-1)^n]}{2\cdot 3^n}\]

so, we now only need to check if the numerators match.

Since $n$ is only used in the numerator as an exponent of the base $-1$, it's sufficient to check the even case and the odd case are the same:

$n$ even: $2\cdot 3^{1+(-1)^n} - 7[1+(-1)^n] = 2\cdot 3^2 - 14 = 4$, while $3-(-1)^{n+1} = 4$.

$n$ odd: $2\cdot 3^{1+(-1)^n} - 7[1+(-1)^n] = 2\cdot 3^0 - 0 = 2$, while $3-(-1)^{n+1} = 2$.

So the two expressions are always equal.

Comment: Thank you Ben. Looks like I'm just gonna have to tell him that your sln. looks nicer and that's it.

Answer (score 3):

This is not really an answer, but a comment on a related issue you might find useful -- Millwood already gave a good answer. You can *derive* the professor's formula -- well, actually a simpler version as you can get rid of $n+1$ in the exponent and replace it with $n$ by a sign change -- as follows:

1. Recognize that $1, -1, 1, -1, ...$ is given by $(-1)^n$ (starting at $n = 0$)
2. Add $1$ to this to get $2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, ... $.
3. Divide this by $2$ to get $1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, ... $.
4. Add $1$ to that to get $2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, ... $.
5. You now have $\frac{(-1)^n + 1}{2} + 1$.
6. Starting at $n = 1$, this is $1, 2, 1, 2, 1, ... $.
7. Just divide by $3^n$ and simplify.
8. To get the original form: multiply and divide $(-1)^n$ by $-1$ to get $n+1$ in the exponent and it as negative.

Done.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{2\cdot 3^{1+(-1)^n}-7(-1)^n+2}{2\cdot 3^n}=\begin{cases}\frac{2+7+2}{2\cdot3^n}=\frac{11}{2\cdot3^n}&,\;\;n\;\;\text{odd}\\{}\\\frac{2\cdot 9-7+2}{2\cdot3^n}=\frac{13}{2\cdot3^n}&,\;\;n\;\;\text{even}\end{cases}$$

It isn't anything close to the other thing, not even for $\;n=1,2\;$ !

Comment: Looks like there was a typo in the original question, since corrected.

Comment: Yes @BenMillwood, it was edited: that denominator $\;2\;$ in the numerator only applied to $\;7(-1)^n\;$ ...Here is the original:  http://i.stack.imgur.com/LO8AD.png

Answer (score 0):

The general term in terms of $n$ for $n=0 .. \infty$ can be expressed by many forms. One is $$  { 3 - (-1)^n \over 2 } \cdot {1 \over 3^{n+1}} $$
Another one is
$$   (1+ \sin({n\pi /2 })^2  ) {1 \over 3^{n+1}} $$
The second form has the advantage, that it can be interpolated to any fractional index $n$ which might be meaningful in some contexts.
Other possibilities are to use any arbitrary one-periodic function giving $0,1,0,1,...$ at consecutive indexes instead of $\sin(n \pi /2)^2$